# React-Admin - Add a show/hide property to TextField?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm new to React. I have an area of a "show" page that is for example:

```
export default (props) => (
<Show title={<Title/>}{...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
      <Tab label="Details">
        <TextField source="id" label="ID"/>
      </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
  </Show>
```

On that TextField, is there something that can be imported and used basically to the same effect of [PasswordMask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-password-mask) to get that functionality on TextField? I see a bunch of tutorials on building out custom stuff, but am looking for the best OOTB approach here. I realize some of my React jargon may not be correct and the question may look ridiculous to an experienced framework user.

Comment: Is the `TextField` a component you created or is it from `Material-UI`? If it is from `Material-UI`, then you can pass the prop `type="password"` to it and that should mask the text you want in there.

Comment: It is from `import { TextField } from 'react-admin';` and adding `type="password"` doesn't appear to have any change.

Comment: Add `source="password" type="password". That should work according to the documentation. Check the `TabbedShowLayout` component here https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Show.html

Comment: In my example above, I would want to apply the logic to the TextField displaying ID where source would still be source="id". Is that still doable?

Comment: I think it should still be doable. Unless there has been a change in their API, I'd say the most important thing is the `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `<TextField>` Component is implemented by you using `<input>` html tag and not `<textarea>`, you can use your TextField Component's state to switch between `<input type="text"...` to  `<input type="password"...` e.g. `<input type={this.state.showPassword ? 'text' : password'}...`